# How to re-enable kubuntu / kde after updating to 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde

So *kubuntu* got disabled after I upgraded to 18.04. When I was asked to delete obsolete packages, I clicked yes. Does anyone know how to re-enable *kubuntu* / *kde* ?

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

and it says it's already installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean "disabled" ? Should be a choice on the login screen

Comment: apt install kubuntu-desktop

Comment: @cmak.fr - the question states "sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop" and it says it's already installed"

Comment: Have you tried *reinstalling* or *reconfiguring* the desktop environment?

Comment: There is no way to choice to chose a different desktop environment. I have not tried uninstalling the default desktop. Not sure how to go about that